# Bootstrap Row Overlaps

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am building a prototype for a chat application using bootstrap. When the screen size is small, there is some overlapping between the rows. I am stuck and have no clue about the reason behind this weird behavior

Code:

```
<body>
    <section class='menu col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 border'>
        <div class='row user'>
            <div class='col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 border'>
                <img class='user-picture' src='img/profile.jpg'></img>
            </div>
            <div class='user-name col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Error</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row dialog-box'>dialogs</div>
    </section>

    <section class='detail col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 border'>
        chat details
    </section>

</body>
```

In big screen, it works fine like this:[image]

But when the screen is smaller, it overlaps like[image] this

Comment: one thing i see is you shouldnt add classes to the section tag. use a div instead. you can just wrap the whole thing in section. another thing is your dialog box isn't using any of the bootstrap grid classes.

Comment: it's best if all `.col-xx-x` class exist within a `.row` container. try adding a `.row` container to `    <section class='detail col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 border'>
`